# Как найти запись в базе данных по двум значениям django 2.2.2 python3

Tags: python-3.x, django

Имеем: models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Dreams(models.Model):
    dream_text = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Dreams

def index(request):
    dreams = Dreams.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'main/index.html', {'dreams' : dreams})

def search(request):
    if 'text' in request.GET and request.GET['text']:
        text = request.GET['text']
        search_result = Dreams.objects.filter(dream_text__icontains=text)
        return render(request, 'main/search.html', {'search_result' : search_result})
    else:
        search_result = ""
        return render(request, 'main/search.html', {'search_result' : search_result})
```

Вопрос: Как сделать поиск не только по

```
search_result = Dreams.objects.filter(dream_text__icontains=text)
```

А и по

```
search_result = Dreams.objects.filter(pub_date__icontains=text)
```

search.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ua" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>OblaCo</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    {% load static %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'main/main_css.css' %}">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="main center">
      <h1 class="logo center"><marquee behavior="alternate" scrollamount="2">OblaCo</marquee></h1>

      {% for i in search_result %}
      <div class="dreams center">
        <h4>{{ i.pub_date }}</h4>
        <h5>{{ i.dream_text }}</h5>
      </div>
      {% endfor %}
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from django.db.models import Q

Dreams.objects.filter(Q(dream_text__icontains=text) | Q(pub_date__icontains=text))
```